# Calculator Decimal Point

Tags: ios, objective-c, decimal, calculator

I've developed a calculator and now would like to add a decimal point into operation.  The code I'm using so far allows the decimal point button to be used and displayed, however when I  click another number after clicking the decimal point, the decimal point disappears.  For example: 2.2 becomes 22.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)NUmber1:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];


}
-(IBAction)NUmber2:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 2;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
}
-(IBAction)NUmber3:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 3;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
}
-(IBAction)NUmber4:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 4;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];

}


- (IBAction)decimal:(id)sender {
    NSRange range = [Screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (range.location ==NSNotFound){
        Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need 10 different IBActions... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41761/how-can-i-condense-several-ibaction-methods-in-a-class-with-a-delegate/41762#41762

Comment: It'd probably be a lot simpler to collect the digits and decimal point as a string and convert to a number only when an operator is tapped.

Comment: BTW, standard practice is always use initial lowercase for variables and method names (e.g. selectNumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
-(IBAction)NUmber1:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
}
```

you are erasing your current string with new INTEGER value. Try to change to

```
-(IBAction)NUmber1:(id)sender{
    Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
}
```

Also you need to change your `SelectNumber` calculation logic. I suggest you to get it from string when you really need it

```
double SelectNumber = [Screen.text doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct behavior based on what you've told it to do.  Let's say you had 2. and then you press 2. SelectNumber was 2, and you multiply by 10 and get 20 and then add 2, so it's 22, then you print it out as an integer.  When you type a number AFTER a decimal place, you can't multiply by 10 any more, you have to add the digit/10^(number of digits so far). Note that you'll have to keep this in a float instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong.

When you respond to a digit key you take `SelectNumber`, multiply it by 10 and add the value of the key. Finally you update the display based on the value just calculated.

However when you respond to the point key you just add a point to the *display*, you don't do anything to change how subsequent digit keys are handled. Therefore, as you have observed, when the next digit key is handled the point in the display is just ignored.

You need to work out any algorithm so that digits after a point have a fractional value.